# Why isn't protium nucleus considered most stable nucleus?

Tags: stability, hydrogen, nuclear, nuclear-chemistry

My chemistry teacher told me that $\ce{^{56}Fe}$ is the most stable nucleus because of the highest binding energy per nucleon.
But if we consider a protium nucleus, it has only 1 proton so there is no chance of separation.
so why isn't protium considered the most stable nucleus?

Comment: Will answer properly later if nobody else does, but firstly the proton is theorised to decay https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay, and secondly read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy - nuclear particles bind together to form lower energy states in a not totally dissimilar way to how atoms bind together to make molecules. There's probably a duplicate here as well

Comment: When he made that statement he was certaintly thinking of nuclei with A > 1, making the interesting point that binding energy per nucleon peaks at Fe-56 (which is important for stellar evolution).  It's obviously not meaningful to talk about binding energy/nucleon for a proton.  As far as Fe56's vs. a proton's comparative stability, Ian's link shows the proton's estimated half-life is 10^34 years!  I don't know if the nuclear binding energy in Fe56 adds to the stability of the proton, nor whether there are any estimates of the half life of the Fe56 nucleus as a whole.

Comment: The stability is meant not as lack of self decay here, but disability to reach lower energy. Analogy:  Nuclei are like pits and nucleons are like tiny balls in a children game. The 56Fe is the deepest pit for the balls/nucleons, while a proton/ball lays on the flat surface. It is conditionally stable, until it falls into a pit/nuclei, where it is more stable ( not in all cases ), as it cannot jump back up.

Comment: Don't forget that "binding energy" is relative. Say the binding energy per nucleon of an isolated proton is 0, then the binding energy per nucleon of an iron nucleus is *lower* than zero (hence nuclear processes in stars can *release* energy by banging protons together to make heavier nuclei like iron (it is way more complex than this in reality but this view captures the essential point).